# Makefile - How to call other makefiles with dependencies

Tags: makefile

Hey, I have a simple "master" Makefile who simply calls other makefiles. I'm trying to do the following in order to build components in the right order:

```
LIB_A = folder_a
LIB_B = folder_b
LIB_C = folder_c

MY_TARGETS = $(LIB_A) $(LIB_B) $(LIB_C)

.PHONY: $(LIB_A)
$(LIB_A):
    @$(MAKE) -C $@;

.PHONY: $(LIB_B)
$(LIB_B):
    @$(MAKE) -C $@;

.PHONY: $(LIB_C)
$(LIB_C): $(LIB_A) $(LIB_B)
    @$(MAKE) -C $@;

.PHONY: all 
all: $(MY_TARGETS)
```

However, when I make, only LIB_A gets built.

(I don't even get a folder_b up-to-date message or whatever).

Any hint ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make `all` the default. You can do this in either of these ways:

- move it to be the first target in the file
- Add `.DEFAULT_GOAL := all`

Alternatively, you could run `make all` instead of just `make`.

Comment: Butterworth: Indeed. That totally fixed it. I didn't know the order of the targets had an impact..

Comment: @turbo In general the order doesn't matter, except that the default is the first. You can also specify the default using some syntax I've forgotten :-)

Comment: And you could of course have said `make all` and your original makefile should have worked.

Comment: In case someone reads this in the future, the syntax you are looking for is `.DEFAULT_GOAL := all` (or whatever your goal is).

Answer (score 8):

Neil Butterworth solved the problem, but you can also make this makefile a little more concise:

```
LIB_A = folder_a
LIB_B = folder_b
LIB_C = folder_c

MY_TARGETS = $(LIB_A) $(LIB_B) $(LIB_C)

.PHONY: all $(MY_TARGETS)
all: $(MY_TARGETS)

$(MY_TARGETS):
    @$(MAKE) -C $@;

$(LIB_C): $(LIB_A) $(LIB_B)
```

Comment: How would you define clean to clean all modules in this example?

Comment: @nilo: I'd change the command to `@$(MAKE) -C $@ $(TARG)`, then add the `clean` rule: `clean: TARG=clean<CR>clean: all`